# DELETE with multiple JOIN in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-delete

I have a SELECT query with multiple JOIN who works perfectly, but now I want to DELETE this rows, and I can't find how.
This code returns me an error SQL (1064):

```
DELETE FROM rapport
INNER JOIN course ON rapport.course_id = course.id
INNER JOIN reunion ON course.reunion_id  = reunion.id
INNER JOIN paris ON rapport.paris_id = paris.id 
WHERE reunion.id = 231431
AND paris.bookmaker_id = 3
```

I need some help, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong.
Use this with aliases also:

```
DELETE r
FROM rapport r
INNER JOIN course c ON r.course_id = c.id
INNER JOIN reunion u ON c.reunion_id  = u.id
INNER JOIN paris p ON r.paris_id = p.id 
WHERE u.id = 231431 AND p.bookmaker_id = 3
```

If you want to delete from all tables then you must specify their aliases after `DELETE`:

```
DELETE r, c, u, p
FROM rapport r
INNER JOIN course c ON r.course_id = c.id
INNER JOIN reunion u ON c.reunion_id  = u.id
INNER JOIN paris p ON r.paris_id = p.id 
WHERE u.id = 231431 AND p.bookmaker_id = 3
```

Comment: Thank you, this is it.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to specify what table to delete from.  Assuming this is `rapport`:

```
DELETE r
    FROM rapport r JOIN
         course c
         ON r.course_id = c.id JOIN
         reunion ru 
         ON c.reunion_id  = ru.id JOIN
         paris p 
         ON r.paris_id = p.id 
    WHERE ru.id = 231431 AND p.bookmaker_id = 3;
```

MySQL also supports deletion from multiple tables.  However, cascading constraints are usually a better approach.

Comment: Thank you, this was good except for the line 8 ( rapport.paris_id -> r.paris_id)